# Convert a date value stored in string format and subtract with current date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate, pymongo, robo3t

I need to apply a query to filter records which are lesser than 50 days. In order to do that, I need to subtract the current date with 50 days and compare with the date field.

The query I tried is :

```
db.getCollection('collection_data').find({"tager.date_from": 
{ $lte : new Date(ISODate().getTime() - (1000 * 86400 * 50)) },
"status": "active"})
```

But the tager.date_from is a string which is like "2020-05-06T12:24:29+00:00" and not like ISODate("2020-05-27T14:57:31.302Z"). So how to convert this in query as well as get the records older than 50 days?

Answer (score 2):

If you can ensure that all strings are in the same timezone and format you can just compare them as strings:

```
db.getCollection('collection_data').find({"tager.date_from": 
{ $lte : new Date(ISODate().getTime() - (1000 * 86400 * 50)).toString() }, 
"status": "active"})
```

Make sure when you convert the date to string you make sure you convert it into the same format and timezone as you have stored.

With that said this is obviously not the recommended solution. you have 2 options:

1. Save the dates as `Date`. this will require you to update your code and database but will be In my opinion the best long term solution.
2. If you're using Mongo version 3.6+ you can use Mongo's [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

```
db.getCollection('collection_data').aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            tagerDate: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$tager.date_from"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            tagerDate: {$lte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - (1000 * 86400 * 50))}
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, this displays all the records and not the records older than 50 days.

Comment: This new Date(ISODate().getTime() - (1000 * 86400 * 90)).toString() prints Fri Feb 28 2020 05:56:42 GMT-0500 (EST), where it can't be able to compare with the string format!

Comment: You're saying the aggregation returns all documents? is the `tagerDate` field created as expected atleast? regarding the `toString`, `Date` has a-lot of different `toString` methods. you should go read and use the proper one for your situation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I am using mongo 3.4@Tom

Comment: Gotcha, so the other options are still valid.as I suggested I personally recommend updating the database to contain strings. if you can't then just find the required string transformation method and use that.

Comment: Thats a lot of process Tom, okay I ll do my best.

Answer (score 0):

You can covert a string to a date in the aggregation framework using [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/). Your date strings are already in the default format required so it is straight forward. For other formats you can pass a format string to `$dateFromString`.

```
> db.test.insert({"date": "2020-05-06T12:24:29+00:00"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.aggregate([{"$project" : { "newdate" : { "$dateFromString" : {"dateString" : "$date" }}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ecf91fab4a2af1a21e3e244"), "newdate" : ISODate("2020-05-06T12:24:29Z") }
>
```

Comment: "Unrecognized expression '$dateFromString'", @Joe

Comment: It's available from Mongo version 3.6+

Comment: Apologies should have included the version I am using which is MongoDB 4.2. Thanks Tom for the clarification. If you are on a version older than 3.6 you are missing out on a ton of features.

Comment: I am using Robo 3T 1.3.1@JoeDrumgoole

Comment: Robo 3T is GUI interface for  MongoDB. It exists independent of the server version.